# How do I prevent for a second textarea editor from showing up?

Tags: jquery, editor

This is what I am trying to accomplish: I have a code that generates a paragraph tag and a div tag, depending on what button is clicked. If I generate a paragraph or a div, I can click either one to select, and click again to deselect. If I select the paragraph that is being generated (the background color changes) a textarea editor shows up, if i deselect, it hides. The same task applies to the div tag. The problem I have for example is that, if I select the p tag and then I try to select the div tag it just swipes textarea editors and I want to prevent that like this: If the element is selected just show the textarea editor for that particular element until I deselect. Then I can select another element and on.

Here is a link if you want to check my project out so you can better understand, and edit if you wish to.
http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/97/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#Test').on('click', '.test-p', function() {
         editEl = $(this);
         $('#editor-d').hide();
         $('#editor-p').show();
         $('#editor-p textarea').val($(editEl).html());
});
$('#Test').on('click', '.test-d', function() {
         editdiv = $(this);
         $('#editor-p').hide();
         $('#editor-d').show();
         $('#editor-d textarea').val($(editdiv).html());
});

$('#editor-p textarea').change(function() {
$(editEl).html($('#editor-p textarea').val());
});
$('#editor-d textarea').change(function() {
$(editdiv).html($('#editor-d textarea').val());
});
$('#editor-p textarea').change(function() {
$(editEl).html($('#editor-p textarea').val());
});
$('#editor-d textarea').change(function() {
$(editdiv).html($('#editor-d textarea').val());});


var pid = 1;
$("#addP").on({
    click: function(){
        var pr = $('<p />').attr({class:'test-p', 'id':'paragraph_' + pid}).text('This is a paragraph ' + pid);
        var d = $("#Test");
        var pclone = $(pr).clone();
        pclone.on({
            mouseenter: function(){    
                $(this).addClass("inside");
            },
            mouseleave: function(){                             
                $(this).removeClass("inside"); 
            },
                    });
        pclone.appendTo(d);
pid++;
    }
});
var divid = 1;
$("#addDiv").on({
    click: function(){
             var div = $('<div />').attr({'class':'test-d', 'id':'div_' + divid}).text('This is a div ' + divid);  
             var d = $("#Test");
             var pclone = $(div).clone();
             pclone.on({
             mouseenter: function(){    
                $(this).addClass("inside");
             },
             mouseleave: function(){                             
                $(this).removeClass("inside"); 
             },
                    });
        pclone.appendTo(d);
divid++;
    }
});

var div =  $('<div class="customD" id="d"></div>');
var del = $('<a href="#" class="delete" id="erase">Delete</a>');

var flag = false;
$("#Test").on("click", "p, div", function(){ 
    var cur = $(this).css("background-color");

     if(cur=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") { 
          if(flag==false){
               $(this).css("background-color","#FDD").addClass("help insider").after(div);
                flag = true;
          }
    }else { 
     $('#editor-p').hide();
     $('#editor-d').hide();

      $(this).css("background-color","white").removeClass('help insider');
      $(div).remove();
 flag = false;
    }    
    $(div).append(del);  

$(".delete").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
$('#editor-p').hide();

flag = false;

});
}); 
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your second text box is a `<input type ="text" />` in your html

Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/97/

If you want to prevent the other divs from being clicked, you should use a variable like 'editingMode=true' and then set to false when you finish editing. Then add an if in the the click event to see if you are in editing mode like if(editingMode){ //the click stuff //}

Hope that helped and that's what you had in mind :)

Comment: Hi miro, I think you forgot to update the Fiddle. The link you posted is the same as mine.